# How can I observe a URL change using class components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a let that contains the current path of my application and I want that if the user enters another path of the url it will be redirected to another one.

Example:

The user is on home and then he clicks on videos, instead of going to videos I want him to be redirected to home.

In the function components I would create a const using useState and use a UseEffect to watch for changes in the URL.

But I don't know how to do this in a class component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use State and componentDidMount() like this

```
class component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      Yourstate: '',
     
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    //Equivalent to useEffect
  }
```